# Unable to remove data from json file on disk

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, file, fs

I'm unable to find a way to remove whole line of JSON data(line) after it's used.
For some reason `delete` is not working or rather said not doing anything.

.JSON

```
[
{"id":"1","code":"super-S","expires_in":"","gives_currencies":"1.5","gives_items":"","number_of_attempts":"1","attempts_used":""},
{"id":"2","code":"wow!","expires_in":"","gives_currencies":"3","gives_items":"","number_of_attempts":"1","attempts_used":""},
{"id":"3","code":"slashme","expires_in":"","gives_currencies":"4","gives_items":"","number_of_attempts":"1","attempts_used":""},
{"id":"4","code":"randombla","expires_in":"","gives_currencies":"5","gives_items":"","number_of_attempts":"1","attempts_used":""}
]
```

code

```
//fs configuration
const fs = require('fs');
let rawdata = fs.readFileSync('test.json');
let mycodes = JSON.parse(rawdata);

//something above
const randomcode = mycodes[Math.floor(Math.random() * mycodes.length)];
console.log('Your code is:', randomcode['code']); //logs me a random code value
delete mycodes[randomcode];
```

The goal here is to select random code, which is done but then I need to remove it from .JSON file so it won't repeat. I tried several things but it's not working, `delete.randomcode` etc... the line never removed from the .JSON file.

Comment: Where in your code are you exactly saving back your JSON (using `JSON.stringify`) to file?

Comment: It's in the exact same dir as the .js file

Comment: That was not my question. Where is the code where you say: "OK, deleted, now save back to that same file"

Comment: I see, sorry, I do not use JSON.stringify anywhere.

Comment: All I have about it is in the post I sent.

Comment: Not sure if my question is formulated in "good" version, all I need is to remove randomly generated code line after it's used. I can randomize the "code" and then do anything with it, but I need to remove it after this from the .JSON file somehow. I wasn't able to find a way to do this and everything what I found was something related to the `delete` ex. `delete MyObj.[yourthing];`

Comment: OK I got yoru question perfectly fine and provided a solution.

Comment: Thank you so much @RokoC.Buljan :-)) All kudos to you!

Comment: You're very welcome. Added another example which uses just that random index.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Array.prototype.**splice**(index, deleteCount)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)  instead of `delete`.
`delete`, on an Array, will just `null` the key, without removing it.

Save back your modified data using `JSON.stringify(mycodes)` to that same file.

```js
const fs = require('fs');

const mycodes = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./test.json'));
const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * mycodes.length);
const randomObject = mycodes[randomIndex];

console.log('Your code is:', randomObject.code); // Log a random code value
mycodes.splice(randomIndex, 1); // Remove one key at randomIndex

// Write back to file
fs.writeFileSync('test.json', JSON.stringify(mycodes, 0, 4), 'utf8');
```

If you already have that Object out of your Array, and since Objects are passed by reference (like pointer in memory), make use of the [Array.prototype.indexOf(someObject)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexof) like:

```js
const fs = require('fs');

const mycodes = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./test.json'));
const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * mycodes.length);
const randomObject = mycodes[randomIndex];

// later in your code....
const objIndex = mycodes.indexOf(randomObject); // Get Object index in Array
mycodes.splice(objIndex, 1); // Remove it from array at that index

// Write back to file
fs.writeFileSync('test.json', JSON.stringify(mycodes, 0, 4), 'utf8');
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to persist your data by writing it back to your JSON file after using [`JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify).

While you're at it, you can move your code into functions, which will make it easier to read and work with.

You might also want to read about editing arrays using [`Array.prototype.splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice).

> The [`delete` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete) is for deleting properties from objects. While you *can* use it to delete elements from an array, it will leave the index empty rather than closing the gap in the array after deletion.

```js
const fs = require('fs');

// get a random element from any array
function getRandomElement (array) {
  const randomElement = array[Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length)];
  return randomElement;
}

function deleteElementFromArray (array, element) {
  const index = array.indexOf(element);
  if (index < 0) return false;
  array.splice(index, 1);
  return true;
}

// move the reading work inside a function
function readJson (filePath) {
  const json = fs.readFileSync(filePath, {encoding: 'utf8'});
  const data = JSON.parse(json);
  return data;
}

// move the reading work inside a function
function writeJson (filePath, data) {
  const json = JSON.stringify(data);
  fs.writeFileSync(filePath, json);
}


const jsonFilePath = 'test.json';

const mycodes = readJson(jsonFilePath);
const randomcode = getRandomElement(mycodes);
console.log('Your code is:', randomcode['code']);

deleteElementFromArray(mycodes, randomcode);
writeJson(jsonFilePath, mycodes);
```